# form submit don't call ajax function phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app with phonegap and I have a `form` to register new users. In the broswer(chrome and firefox), the form works fine when correctly 
filled, and show errors if something wrong.  I have an `alert('work!');` in the start of function to check if was called, in browsers the alert appears but in the app no. What can be? 
Ps: I already have `<access origin="">` to my website where's the php file of form is.

**EDIT:**

the form:

```
<form id="cadastro" method="post">

                <input type="text" style="height:30px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;font-size:18px" name="nome" id="textinput-2" placeholder="Nome" required>   
                <input type="text" style="height:30px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:18px" name="email" id="textinput-1" placeholder="Email" required>
                <div id="email_erro"></div>

                <input type="password" style="height:30px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:18px" name="senha" id="password" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="off" required>
                <input type="password" style="height:30px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:18px" name="repetir_senha" id="re_password" placeholder="Repetir senha" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="senha_erro"></div>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="margin-left:5%" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="radio-choice-c" value="m" checked="checked" required>
                            <label for="radio-choice-c">Masculino</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="radio-choice-d" value="f" required>
                            <label for="radio-choice-d">Feminino</label>
                </fieldset>       
                <div style="margin-left:3.5%;margin-right:4%;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="checkbox-mini-0" value="1" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="checkbox-mini-0">Quero receber as ofertas e novidades</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="termo" id="checkbox-mini-1" data-mini="true" required>
                        <label for="checkbox-mini-1">Aceito os Termos de Uso e Política de privacidade</label>
                    <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" id="termo" style="float:none;margin-left:2%">Criar conta</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

the function:

```
<script>
        alert('entrou no script');
        $('#cadastro').submit(function(){
            var valor = $('#cadastro').serialize();


    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cadastro',
    dataType: "json",
    data: valor

    }).success(function(response){
        alert('retornou função');
        if (response.sucesso) { 

            window.localStorage["email"] = response.dados.email;
            window.localStorage["nome"] = response.dados.nome;                             
            window.localStorage["sexo"] = response.dados.sexo;                             
            window.localStorage["id"] = response.dados.id; 
            //window.localStorage["UID"] = data.uid; 
            window.location = "logado.html";
        } else {
            alert("Verifique seus dados");

            $('#email_erro').html(response.erro_email);
            $('#senha_erro').html(response.erro_repetir_senha);

            //window.location("main.html");
            }

    });
    return false;
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can we see the pertinent codes for this please?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post.

Comment: Are you including the cordova javascript file? - <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, this is included

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is because you are running your javascript before the phonegap framework has loaded. Try using the event listener below, and then place your javascript in the corresponding function.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
    // PhoneGap has loaded - your code goes here
}
```